# JQuery Typer effect not working in HTML

Tags: jquery, html

This is my first time writing a website (personal page) and I'm having trouble getting a JQuery effect to work in the website. I found this code online (which basically says to add this to your webpage for it to work) but all that shows up is "foo" on the bottom of the page:

```
<div id="typer">foo</div>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='jquery.typer.js'></script>     
    <script>
        var win = $(window),
            foo = $('#typer');
        foo.typer(['TEXT A', 'TEXT B', 1337]);
    </script>
</div>
```

This is all located in the bottom of the  of my page. Am I missing something that will make the JQuery run?

Comment: Try placing your script tags outside and after the `#typer` div. jQuery can't access elements that aren't available yet, and having them inside may be too soon. Can we assume that jquery.typer.js is present and in the same folder as your HTML file?

Comment: Enclose your code in a document-ready clause.

Comment: jquery.typer.js is in the same folder as the html code. and i tried moving around the script tags, but that still didn't work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either:
You're executing the code too early. Add a document-ready clause:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var win = $(window),
        foo = $('#typer');
        foo.typer(['TEXT A', 'TEXT B', 1337]);
    });
</script>
```

Or:
It's possible you haven't got the file in the right place. Is the file `jquery.typer.js` included in the same folder as your HTML file? If not, find it, download it, and include it there, or link to it the same way you have with jQuery.

Comment: I added the document-ready clause and reinstalled the jquery.typer.js and put it in the same folder as the html file. Still not working unfortunately